# programmatically bounce a service

Tags: service, windows-server-2003

We have a 3rd party program that appears to have some sort of an issue that requires that it be bounced regularly, say, every 2 days.

How can we do this programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a PowerShell script:

```
Restart-Service "YourServiceName"
```

[source](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_service_restart.htm)

Answer (score 2):

You could run a scheduled task that runs a batch file which contains:

```
net.exe stop "service name"
net.exe start "service name"
```